# Why doesn't the vector change its elements?

Tags: c++, vector

Have a vector which contains pointers to a Student class. I need to selection sort the vector elements only changing the pointers, not the content. Here is my caller code:

```
StudentsFileReader* sfr = new StudentsFileReader(filepath);

cout << "Calling sortPositionExchange..." << endl;

SelectionSort::sortPositionExchange(&(sfr->getStudents()));

cout << "Done!" << endl;
```

Here is my calling code:

```
void SelectionSort::sortPositionExchange(vector<Student*>* students)
{
    int i, j, min, aux, tam = students->size();

    for (i = 0; i < tam - 1; i++)
    {
        min = i;
        for (j = (i + 1); j < tam; j++)
        {
            if (students->at(j)->getCode() < students->at(min)->getCode())
            {
                min = j;
            }
        }

        if (i != min)
        {
            Student* s = students->at(i);
            *(&students->at(i)) = *(&students->at(min));
            *(&students->at(min)) = s;
        }
    }
}
```

The selection sort executes perfectly inside sortPositionExchange function, but when it returns, the vector keeps unchanged.

What can I do to persist the changes between calling functions?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the problem is in `getStudents()` and not in the code here.

Comment: Also in c++ I would prefer to pass a vector by reference over using a pointer to a vector.

Comment: Thanks @drescherjm ! I'm gonna look at getStudents() an let you know

Comment: `*(&x)` is the same as `x`

Comment: `&(sfr->getStudents())` is suspicious. You should rewrite your code to not use the `&` operator (even if you still want to persist with a vector of pointers). And post your `getStudents` function.

Answer (score 0):

Your method `getStudents()` returns a vector, the returned vector is not the original vector, it is a copy of it.
In order to fix your issue, make the method `getStudents()` return a reference to the original vector.
so your method should look something like this:

```
vector<Student*>* getStudents() {

    return &studentsVector;
}
```

and your call should look something like this:

```
SelectionSort::sortPositionExchange(sfr->getStudents());
```

Another solution would be to make a method inside `StudentsFileReader` that uses `SelectionSort::sortPositionExchange` to sort the vector. This would look something like:

```
void StudentsFileReader::sortPositionExchange() {

    SelectionSort::sortPositionExchange(students);
}
```

Comment: Note: This breaks encapsulation of `StudentsFileReader`, and breaks lifetime management (the pointer goes invalid as soon as the `StudentsFileReader` goes away, but because it's a pointer, not a reference, maintainers may not realize they don't own what it points to). It may solve the problem at hand, but it creates other issues.

Comment: Re. your first sentence - `getStudents` cannot return by value, because `&` cannot be applied to a prvalue.  It must return by reference already (but perhaps it returns a dangling reference to a local copy, or something)